# How to set matlab xticks equal distance with unequal numerical spaces?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting data which is polynomial but I would like to show it on a straight line so that it is clearer.

I want the x-axis tick marks to show N^2 where N is the tick location. I also want the actual ticks on the graph to be evenly spaced even though the numbers aren't.

I tried to change the ticks using

xtick_squared = (0:10:100).^2
set(gca,'xTick',xtick_squared,'xTickLabel',xtick_squared)

but it gives this 
[image]

How can I display them each being even spaced while reatining their values as well as adjusting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
x = 0:10:100;
y = (x .^ 2) + 5;
labs = sprintfc('%d',x.^2);

plot(x,y);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labs);
```

Actually, it's all about changing the tick labels without changing the ticks themselves. Here is the final output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the location of x-ticks and then rename them.

Here is the code example:

```
 x=[0,10,20,30,40,50].^2;
 plot(x,x)
 set(gca,'XTick',linspace(0,2500,6),'XTickLabels',num2cell(x))
```

P.S.: Note, that your actual data is plotted on evenly spaced grid. I've just renamed the ticks' names.

Edit: if you want to plot your actual data, you need to scale `x`-axis correspondingly. If you want to `plot(x,x)` you need to call `plot(sqrt(x),x)` instead:

```
 x=[0,10,20,30,40,50].^2;
 plot(sqrt(x),x)
 set(gca,'XTick',linspace(0,2500,6),'XTickLabels',num2cell(x))
```

Comment: but how can I make my actual data spaced like this?

Comment: By scaling x-axis. There might be an easier way, but I am not aware of it